# How to get this STRING value instead of ID

Tags: php, xml

Good day. Hope someone can help me solve this problem of mine in getting the actual String value instead of id.

```
<Pull_ListSpecProp_RS>
    <Property>
        <Amenities>
              <Amenity Count="1">2</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">4</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">6</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="2">19</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">74</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">115</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">124</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">125</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">140</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">174</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">180</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">187</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">395</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">589</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">792</Amenity>
              <Amenity Count="1">798</Amenity>
        </Amenities>
    <Property>    
</Pull_ListSpecProp_RS>
```

**

```
<Pull_ListAmenities_RS>
    <Amenities>
       <Amenity AmenityID="2">Cookware &amp; Kitchen Utensils</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="3">Crockery &amp; Cutlery</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="4">Iron &amp; Ironing Board</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="5">Drying Rack</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="6">Hair Dryer</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="7">Bed Linen &amp; Towels</Amenity>
       <Amenity AmenityID="8">Toiletries</Amenity>
    </Amenities>
</Pull_ListAmenities_RS>
```

if (Amenity == AmenityID) if True, I want the return value to be the string value of the 2nd Amenity response.

example Amenity= 2 and AmenityID= 2 the return value will be

```
if(Amenity == AmenityID){
  echo Amenity;
}

//Output Cookware &amp; Kitchen Utensils
```

This is my current code

```
foreach($Pull_ListSpecProp_RQ->Property->Amenities->Amenity as $AmenityID){ //This foreach is to get all the available Amenity of a specific/selected room
   foreach ($Pull_ListAmenities_RQ->Amenities->Amenity as $Amenity) { //This for each is to get all the List of amenities.
     //echo "ID: ".$Amenity['AmenityID']."<br/>";
     if ($AmenityID == $Amenity['AmenityID']) {
       echo "ID: ".$Amenity."<br/>";
     }
   }
}
```

Hope my question and explanation is understandable. Sorry for this dumb question of mine. im not a good programmer, yet :).

Comment: can you paste a `var_dump($Amenity)` please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `$AmenityID` and `$Amenity`are of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

These have a method [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) which will return the string content.

Maybe you can compare the string content of `$AmenityID` with the `AmenityID` attribute of `$Amenity`.

For example:

```
foreach($Pull_ListSpecProp_RQ->Property->Amenities->Amenity as $AmenityID){ 
    foreach ($Pull_ListAmenities_RQ->Amenities->Amenity as $Amenity) {
        if ($AmenityID->__toString() === $Amenity->attributes()->AmenityID->__toString()) {
            echo $Amenity->__toString() . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just `if ((string) $AmenityID === (string) $Amenity->attributes()->AmenityID) {`

Comment: half the point of the `__toString()` magic method, is that you _don't_ have to call it. `echo $Amenity;` is enough.